# How can search node search by tag element

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, linq-to-xml

I have a complex XML file, and I should parse it with C# language.

So this is a simple section of it:

```
<ClinicalDocument>
    <component>
    <section>
        <templateId root='2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.11'/> <!-- Problem section template -->
        <code code="11450-4" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"/> 
        <title>Problems</title> 
        <text></text>
         .......
    </section>
    </component>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Now I want to search all element of this XML file where templateId root="2.x.x.x".

I have build this code but not works:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(_xmlName);
            XElement element =
            doc.Element("section")
                .Descendants("templateId")
                .Where(a => a.Element("root").Value.Equals(_TEMPLATE_ID_PROBLEM))
                    .First();
```

> EDIT

I have change my code with this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(_xmlName);
            XElement element =
            doc.Element("ClinicalDocument").Element("component").Element("section")
                .Descendants("templateId")
                .Where(a => a.Element("root").Value.Equals(_TEMPLATE_ID_PROBLEM))
                    .First();
```

But I have an error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  _HResult=-2147467261
  _message=Riferimento a un oggetto non impostato su un'istanza di oggetto.
  HResult=-2147467261
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Riferimento a un oggetto non impostato su un'istanza di oggetto.
  Source=XmlParser_Decipher
  StackTrace:
       in XmlParser_Decipher.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\michele.castriotta\Source\Workspaces\Omniacare\XmlParser_Decipher\XmlParser_Decipher\Program.cs:riga 19
       in System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       in System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       in Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I have try to do this:

```
XElement element =
            doc.Element("ClinicalDocument");
```

and the var element is null.

Comment: "but not works" doesn't tell us anything about what actually happened compared with expectations. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: (I note that `doc.Element("section")` won't work because that's not the root element, mind you...

Answer (score 0):

`section` is a child of document root:

```
doc.Root.Element("section")
```

also `root` is not element - it's an attribute of `templateId` element:

```
.Where(t => (string)t.Attribute("root") == _TEMPLATE_ID_PROBLEM)
```

Full query will look like

```
doc.Root.Element("section")
   .Descendants("templateId") // you can use Elements here
   .Where(t => (string)t.Attribute("root") == _TEMPLATE_ID_PROBLEM)
   .First();
```

And another option is using XPath:

```
doc.Root.XPathSelectElement($"section/templateId[@root='{_TEMPLATE_ID_PROBLEM}']");
```